# Precise Async Timing

Tags: python, asynchronous, audio, pygame

Making a "music box" program. Right now, my code effectively calls:

```
note.play()
time.sleep(0.08)
note.play()
time.sleep(0.16)
note.play()
time.sleep(0.12)
```

However, the timings are a little off, making the music sound different each time played. I want precision.

How best to approach this? Pygame loop with timedeltas? Async await stuff?

Comment: note: pygame is just to play audio files directly. I'd appreciate other audio library recommendations.

Comment: I'm working on a library that allows playback at exactly specified times: https://github.com/mgeier/python-rtmixer/. It's still very much work in progress, but you can give it a try, if you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't trust a computer's clock. So what you can do is play recorded silence where you want silence.

Check this out: [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)

You can easily concatenate audio tracks. So if you have 0.01 seconds of silence recorded in a file you can concatenate first note with silence track 8 times to get note + 0.08 seconds of silence, and then concatenate to another note and so on.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I am going to: splice together bits with pydub, save the file, then play the file with pygame. It's a little cumbersome, but should work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. If I figure out a better way I'll tell you!